# Why is there overflow in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, overflow

This loop loops all the way down to -30808 and I don't know why! I want it to count down to 1 or 0 from 100.

The stop condition is less than num or 1.

What's wrong with it?

Thanks

```
function first(num){
       for (let i = num - 1; i > num || 1; i--){
         let numFactorial = i;
          console.log(numFactorial);
       }
    };
  first(100);
```

Comment: `i > num || 1` is always true, because `i > num` **OR** `1` and one is true.

Comment: Because your stop test  `i > num || 1` is really `(i > num) || (1)` which will always be true. So it won't stop. Jane, stop this crazy thing!

Comment: You are setting i to num - 1 and decrementing it and your loop termination is checking for when i gets greater than num. It will always be less than num.

Comment: Thank you! So how should I rewrite it?

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing i as num -1 and starting to decrement, which means it is never going to be greater than num. If you are trying to continue the loop as long as i is greater than or equal to 1 then it should be as below.

```
for (let i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--)
```

Also anytime you are trying to compare a variable with two different conditions with || or && pls do as below and not `i > num || 1` here you are comparing i with num but not with 1.

i > num || i >= 1